# A class opens a Filestream for writing in the constructor. How can you assure that the file stream is closed when the garbage collector kicks in?

Tags: java, constructor, garbage-collection, filereader

I'm facing this problem through and java interview. They also ask:

What is a better alternative in java to process files for writing while assuring that they are closed properly?

My solution is to use try/finally statement in the constructor and my alternative is to encapsulate the file operations into specific method and use filereader to deal with text and fileinputstream to deal with media files.

I'm asking the question here to see if I have better solution.

The tag for C++ here is because this role is a C++/java role. So the interviewer also asks about my idea about this question in C++.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @NathanOliver They ask about java, but it's a C++/java role. So it might be better to have C++ version(dealing files in constructors).

Comment: Does the code you need to come up with need C++?  If not then C++ should not be a tag here.

Comment: The answer to your question is completely different in Java and in C++, please pick only one.

Comment: In C++ a garbage collector is (usually) not a thing... Use RAII instead.

Comment: I'm guessing that the constructor would open the filestream, and the stream is to remain opened for other operations, but if the object is set to null, then the object could be flagged for garbage collection before the stream is closed. The answer I would give would be to override `finalize` to close the stream. For object oriented C++, you would want to close the stream in the deconstructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of dealing with this in Java is to simply close the stream yourself once you are about to remove your last reference to it. The garbage collector does not kick in as long as the object is still referenced to.

Whilst Java has a sort of destructor through the implementation of a `finalize()` method, it is not guaranteed to be called. Should there be enough memory available and therefore no need to reuse it, you may still end up wasting OS resources.

Answer (score 1):

He may be looking for an answer such as 'make the class implement `AutoCloseable`', in which case try-with-resources could be used.